# Top rounded corner on an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

How to add top rounded corners to an ImageView. 
I've tried with the following method and it doesn't work.

```
imgView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to create drawable file with radius just on top and set as a background.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a drawable for this or use this library for better result

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom backgroung

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<corners android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

set in imageview like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```